# Kofax invalid ProgID

Tags: c#, kofax

I created a WinForms app and want to use it as a Kofax Export Connector. This app contains a `Setup` class and a `Release` class. The project itself is called `KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA`.

When I try to register the `.inf` file in the Administration module of Kofax using this code

```
[Scripts]
KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA
[KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA]
SetupModule=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.exe
SetupProgID=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.Setup
SetupVersion=1.0
ReleaseModule=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.exe
ReleaseProgID=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.Release
ReleaseVersion=1.0
SupportsNonImageFiles=True
RemainLoaded=True
SupportsKofaxPDF=True
SupportsOriginalFileName=True
SupportsMultipleInstances=False
```

I get an error message

> invalid ProgID

What do I have to fill in here

`SetupProgID=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.Setup`

and here

`ReleaseProgID=KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.Release`

? I thought I would have to specify which class has to be registered for the setup and release.

Comment: Probably it is not valid due to your name is too long.

Comment: the name is too long? What is the maximum amount of letters?

Comment: I am sorry, I think it is correct due to the only limited is the name of the script that is limited up to 255 characteres. Did you build the project that contains your Setup and Release classes with the COM Interop enabled? Remember that SetupProgID and ReleaseProdID should correspond to ProjectName.ClassName

Comment: sorry what did you mean by `COM Interop enabled` ? I built the project and put the `.inf` file next to the `.exe` file.

Comment: In visual studio if you open the properties of the project in "Build" Section I guess you must have the Register for COM Interop option enabled

Comment: sorry I can't find it, where can I get it? I just added the dll files for the code

Comment: Just like this: https://cloud.radl.wien/index.php/s/eDz9BJ0H4dFZdzw

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your assemblies are COM-visible and that your ProgID is unique (system-wide) - see screenshot below.
2. When installing your Export Connector on any machine, make sure the assemblies were registered correctly using regasm. Without that, the COM client (i.e. Kofax Capture) would not be able to see them. Example call: `RegAsm.exe KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.dll /codebase /tlb:KofaxExportConnectorCoBRA.tlb`
3. Your `SetupModule` and `ReleaseModule` cannot be exe files, but should rather point to a dll - so, don't start with a Windows Forms App in Visual Studio. A Kofax Export Connector always has to be a class library with an optional setup form. The minimum you need are two classes, one implementing `IReleaseSetupScript`, and the other one `IReleaseScript` (for more details, refer to the Kofax samples and have a look at [Kofax - How to make Release Script configuration dependent on an active job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342996/kofax-how-to-make-release-script-configuration-dependent-on-an-active-job)). Your export will then either run in the context of Admin.exe for the setup part, and Release.exe for the release part.

[image: COM-visible assemblies in .NET]

Comment: I created a .NET class lib as you did. I did step one and created a .bat file with this content `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe C:\Users\velms\Desktop\Kofax_CoBRA_Export\Kofax_CoBRA_Export\bin\Debug\Kofax_CoBRA_Export.dll /codebase /tlb:Kofax_CoBRA_Export.tlb` and run it as Admin. Further I created this code structure https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/391906188847087616/494435138201976853/unknown.png and run this `.inf` code https://pastebin.com/x3M40La9 . When selecting the `.inf` file in the admin module I am not able to select the connector. What's wrong?

Comment: I created a new thread for this because it might be a new topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52515723/register-kofax-export-connector-in-the-administration-module